# SubSonic3 clearing test data/database in unit test TearDown operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic, nunit, subsonic3

I'm writing some unit tests for an ASP.NET MVC controller that's using SubSonic3 generated model objects (using ActiveRecord "mode" (not sure what else to call it), and am wondering how I can clear out the test data from the test database in my TestFixture's TearDown method. I don't have a direct reference to the model object in my test class, as its a model object that's created by a ControllerAction, so I can't seem to figure out how to clear out the data. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry...I figured it out. `MyModelClass.ResetTestRepo()` did it for me.